# iPhone app localize and change name of the app based on each country app store

Tags: iphone, localization, xcode

I have found how to localize my app and how to change the name of the app for each locale the user has but could anyone tell me if i can change the name of the app in the app store?

What i mean is the following.

My app is called "helo" in the english app store. If a user is from italy and tries to find my app in the italian app store i want the app name to be "ciao". Is this possible by using localization system in the xcode?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In itunesconnect, go to your app details, and then version details. In the top-right corner, press the 'Manage Localizations' button.

From here you can add all the app version details for each localization you want to support. This includes the app name (display name on iTunes), description, what's new, keywords, etc.

For more information, see the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf), *Adding a New Localization*, pg. 63.

Comment: +1 Found this useful too.  An add-on question... in the Italian app store, if a user searches by 'helo', will the app still come through in the search results?

Comment: @DanyalAytekin did you figure out the answer to that question? If a user searches by 'helo', will the app still come through in the search results? in the italian App Store

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022 in App Store Connect app name and subtitle are located on the "App Information" section.