# How to assign a different app name in Google Play for each country

Tags: android, google-play

I want to change the name of my app in the Google Play for each country.

For example: In USA people should see it in Google Play as "Hello", in Turkey "Merhaba" etc..

Turns out you can do this in iPhones but does Android also support this? If yes, how?

iPhone: [iPhone app localize and change name of the app based on each country app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118281/iphone-app-localize-and-change-name-of-the-app-based-on-each-country-app-store)

Comment: Hi have you found the solution to this?

Comment: Hello, have you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

To translate & localize your app: Sign in to your Play Console. Select an app. On the left menu, click Store presence > Store listing. Under "Product Details," click Manage translations > Add your own translation text. Choose a language. Add your translations. Save your changes.

[Play Console Help Pages](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3125566?hl=en)

Answer (score -2):

In AndroidManifest file:

```
  <application android:label="@string/app_label">
```

and create many localized strings.xml files inside /res/values/, /res/values-ru, /res/values-es, etc.

Comment: That's about the app name installed in phones, not the app name shown in the "google play"